# Calculating Vp in a half-wave rectified sine wave

Tags: circuit-analysis

If a half-wave rectified sine wave has an average voltage of 25V, how would I calculate the peak voltage?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like homework with no attempt shown.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume this is a homework assignment, so in keeping with tradition here, only hints are given.

The average voltage of a half-wave rectified cycle - so you want to integrate over a half cycle and divide by \$2\pi\$ radians (since the voltage is zero for the missing half cycle- each half is \$\pi\$ radians). That is the average voltage over a full cycle, and since all the  cycles look pretty much the same it should be the average for any number integral cycles (or close to what you get over any interval containing a large number of cycles).

Suppose the sine wave is \$v(t) = k \sin(\omega t)\$, then find the definite integral between 0 and \$\pi\$ in terms of \$k\$, and divide by \$2\pi\$.

We know that number is equal to 25, so you can find k, which is the peak voltage of the sine wave.

Hint: you will find it is 'about' 80V.

Answer (score -1):

To go the direction you are wanting to go:

25V*sqrt(2) = 35.4Vp

To go the other way, simply divide by sqrt(2)

This assumes that you have a capacitor filter without significant droop.  If you are looking at the rectified signal only without filtering, then it would be doubled:

2 * 25V * sqrt(2) = 70.71Vp

Comment: 25/sqrt(2) = 17.68 not 35.4

Comment: likewise what is the assumption of an included capacitor based upon

Comment: Ha!  You got me!  I had originally had 0.7071 there, but then replaced it.  My bad.  Corrected, but the answer above is better than mine anyway :)